# Javascript String.split should split binary string with 1 as separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary

since
`"this,is,a,comma,separated,sentence".split(",");` will output

```
["this", "is", "a", "comma", "separated", "sentence"]
```

Then why `"1000010001001".split("1")` splitting not working as expected i.e `["0000", "000", "00"]`. Instead it outputs

```
["", "0000", "000", "00", ""]
```

Comment: it works as intended.

Comment: @NinaScholz explanation, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the substrings to be split on exist on the edges of the string, or exist consecutively in the string, the empty string will be the result in those positions.

Given `n` substrings to split on in the string, the result will *always* contain `n + 1` strings as a result.

For example:

```
aba
```

when split on `a`, will produce

```
['', 'b', '']
```

because `'' + 'a' + 'b' + 'a' + ''` is equivalent to the original string of `aba`.

`1000010001001` works the same way.

```
1000010001001
^    ^   ^  ^
```

```
'' + '1' + '0000' + '1' + '000' + '1' + '00' + '1' + ''
```

An example with consecutive substrings to be split on, which the exact same logic applies to:

```js
console.log('abba'.split('b'));
```

Comment: It is also documented as such: `If separator appears at the beginning (or end) of the string, it still has the effect of splitting.  The result is an empty (i.e. zero length) string, which appears at the first (or last) position of the returned array.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#parameters